# UIImageView not gets Focused on tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, storyboard, tvos

I have the following `UIViewController` which i am doing in story board.

[image: StoryBoad]

The problem i am facing here is that when i try to swipe right on tv remote my `UIImageView` does not get any focus. Infact no focus event happen, it try to put some logs in

```
 override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)
```

but  there is no focus event updated.  Earlier i have `UIImageView` directly added on `self.view` in storyboard but i read somewhere the `UIImageView` itself is not focusable so i put my `UIImageView` inside another `UIView`, but it still does not gets any focus. I have aligned top edges of `UIView` which contains `UIImageView` and `UITextView`.

Any help will be highly appreciated

On a side note i also tried to do with UIFocusGuide but that didn't work also. I think i don't need to use UIFocusGuide because it a basic right swipe focus thing.

Comment: @Madu- I have same issue. Can you tell me that how to resolve it. i have also try the following answer. but i don't get success.

Comment: Finally what i did is added a collectionview and in collectionviewcell added an imageView. That did the job for me at least

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UIImageView` is not by default focusable, and will not get focus effect, you can do two things to make it focusable.

1. Subclass `UIImageView` and in subclass override `canBecameFocused` and
   return `YES`, and then override `didUpdateFoucsInContext` and update appearance for focus state, like if focus make it bigger or change color etc.
2. Second option is add it to a view which is focusable and then set `imageView.adjustImageWhenAncestorFocused = YES` also set `clipToBounds = NO` on `superview`

So In your case as you are adding imageView to a view then that view should return YES/True from canBecameFocused.

Comment: There is typo in second case: adjustImageWhenAncestorFocused should be adjust**s**ImageWhenAncestorFocused.

Comment: Hello, Adnan. I tried subclassing and overriding the canBecomeFocused and didUpdateFocusInContext methods but there are no focus updates updating, still. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your view hierarchy? And if you are adding view to some other view then make sure you are overriding canBecomeFocused method.

Answer (score 2):

@C_X is right. The most important thing is that if `UIImageView` is added to `self.view` then don't forget to subclass `self.view` and override the `canBecameFofused` method.

Comment: NOTE too that you must set interactable on the view or image

Answer (score 0):

##### It is now extremely easy to focus an image view in AppleTV, with all the effects included:

Your image will be part of table view or collection view. Then just set

```
adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
```

That's all it is.